# ¿Cómo detectar que la aplicación ya está abierta y traerla al frente?

Tags: java

Estaba haciendo una aplicación en Java y me preguntaba si existiría alguna manera de saber si al ejecutar esta aplicación desde el acceso directo, detectase que ya se está ejecutando y me abra ese proceso como sucede con la aplicación de escritorio Spotify.

He encontrado un método "casero" para saber si ya se encuentra en ejecución; guardo la hora actual con `Java.util.Calendar.getTimeInMillis()` en un bloc de notas cada x segundos, si al intentar abrir la aplicación desde un acceso directo la hora guardada en el txt es menor que x significa se encuentra en ejecución y no me abriría otra copia. Con esto me aseguro que solo se pueda abrir una vez, pero me gustaría que no solo fuese capaz de eso sino que además, encontrase ese proceso y lo mandara al frente.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No hay un metodo específico, pero un *workaround* habitual en swing es aplicar `frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);` y justo después `frame.setAlwaysOnTop(false);` para que se ponga en primer plano. Esto, aplicado junto al metodo que detecta si la aplicación está abierta, te dará el resultado esperado.

Otro metodo seria usar una `ManagementFactory` que solo permitiera una instancia de la aplicación como se explica [aqui](http://web.archive.org/web/20090529082521/http://www.trap17.com/index.php/how-implement-single-instance-application-java_t59760.html)  (link en inglés)

---

Otra cosita:

> He encontrado un método "casero" para saber si ya se encuentra en ejecución; guardo la hora actual con `Java.util.Calendar.getTimeInMillis()` **en un bloc de notas cada x segundos**...

El metodo lo veo bien, eso si:

- escribe en un archivo de texto o fichero a tu eleccion
- con escribir una sola vez la hora tienes suficiente
  *<sup>**no** es necesario escribir cada `X` segundos, solamente la **primera vez** al arrancar, asi podrás liberar recursos.</sup>*

Answer (score 0):

Hola una solución sencilla es mediante un ServerSocket. Primero es crear el server socket, asignarle un puerto, y cachar la Exception, aquí podrías tratar la excepción para que se adapte a lo que propones (si ocurre dicha excepción  puedes terminar tu programa  o lanzarlo al frente (maximizar)porque ya está el otro corriendo ahí). Pero tienes que escoger bien el puerto para que no sea algo que otro programa vaya a usar.

```
try {
  SERVER_SOCKET = new ServerSocket(NUMERO_PUERTO);
  System.out.println("Es la primera instancia de la aplicación...");

} catch (IOException x) {
  System.out.println("Otra instancia de la aplicación se está ejecutando...");
}
```

Display en Top:

```
frame.setAlwaysOnTop( true );
```